# pyspark streaming twitter json to DF

Tags: python, json, apache-spark

I am working on Integration `spark-streaming` with `twitter` using `python` API. Mostly examples or code-snippets and blogs I have seen is that they are taking few columns from `Twitter` `JSON` file for their final manipulation. But according to my use-case I required all fields of `twitter` `JSON` and convert it to a dataframe. This is where I am facing the problem as I `sqlContext.read.json()` is dumping whole `JSON` `DStream` into `_corrupt_record`

> ```
> +--------------------+
> |     _corrupt_record|
> +--------------------+
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> |{u'quote_count': ...|
> ```

Also, It seems that this problem can be solved using `structured streaming` using spark 2+ version. But I have to stick to `spark 1.6`. Following is my code snippet.

```
def process(time, rdd):
    print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
    try:

        sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)

        jsonRDD = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
        jsonRDD.registerTempTable("tweets")
        jsonRDD.printSchema()
    except:
        pass


rawKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "kafka-consumer", {kafkaTopic: 4})
parsed_stream = rawKafkaStream.map(lambda rawTweet: json.loads(rawTweet[1]))

parsed_stream.foreachRDD(process)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `json.dumps()` creates dictionary RDD of type RDD[Dict] in Spark. To make it into DF the following line will work

```
SQLContext.jsonRDD(RDD[dict].map(lambda x: json.dumps(x)))
```

To make it to work in my case I had to do the following

```
def process(time, rdd):
    print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
    try:

        sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)

        jsonRDD=sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd.map(lambda x: json.dumps(x)))
        jsonRDD.registerTempTable("tweets")
        jsonRDD.printSchema()
    except:
        pass


rawKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "kafka-consumer", {kafkaTopic: 4})
parsed_stream = rawKafkaStream.map(lambda rawTweet: json.loads(rawTweet[1]))

parsed_stream.foreachRDD(process)
```

For more detail on this approach. Refer to the [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2870)

Answer (score 2):

Either skip parsing in Python:

```
rawKafkaStream.map(lambda rawTweet: rawTweet[1]).foreachRDD(process)
```

or don't use JSON reader:

```
def process(time, rdd):
    try:
        sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)
        # May or may not work correctly without schema (see below)
        jsonRDD = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
        jsonRDD.registerTempTable("tweets")
        jsonRDD.printSchema()
    except:
        pass
```

In general with both methods you should provide schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([...])
jsonRDD = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(rdd)
```

and

```
jsonRDD = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I am able to convert this transformed RDD which is in the form of python dictionary in `Row()` `RDD` like `row_rdd = parsed_stream.map(lambda x: Row(**x))` ? This is what I am trying to achieve now

Comment: `Row(**x)`  won't work unless structure is a) homogeneous, b) flat. Both methods shown above will work even if these conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: Ok. Yeah got that. BUt If i need to define the schema then how will I map nested columns in RDD and define nested columns schema?

Comment: Each level of nesting is denoted by `StructField`. The easiest way to start going it to use schema, that would be infered by JSON reader - take a bunch of JSON objects (not, `dicts`), put in RDD, apply `read.json`, get `schema`. `sqlContext.read.json(rdd)` alone will work, just will be slower / more costly than it has to be.