# pyspark read json return _corrupt_record

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm working with `pyspark` and [kafka-utils](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createStream), but it's returning _corrupt_record. I set the *[multiLine](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html)* to **True**, but it didn't work. Am I forgetting some configuration?

[image: _corrupt_record]

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve] and errors as text, not images

Comment: it worked as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326058/pyspark-streaming-twitter-json-to-df/50328487#50328487)

Answer (score -1):

please try to use read multi-line JSON in the code as follows.

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("C:\\data\\nested-data.json")
```

Comment: Question is tagged pyspark and is asking about streaming data from Kafka, not files on disk